# Proving $\lim_{x\to 4} \left(\frac{\sqrt {2x-1}}{\sqrt {x-3}}\right) = \sqrt 7$ using $ \varepsilon - \delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\to 4} \left(\frac{\sqrt {2x-1}}{\sqrt {x-3}}\right) = \sqrt 7$$ using $\varepsilon - \delta$.

We find $\delta$ such that
$0<|x-4| <\delta$

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt {2x-1}}{\sqrt {x-3}}-\sqrt 7\right|= \left|\frac{\sqrt {2x-1}-\sqrt{7x-21}}{\sqrt {x-3}}\right|$$

I know that we should get to $|x-4|$ but i dont know how

Comment: But $\lim_{x\to7}\frac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x-3}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}2$.

Comment: Perhaps it should be $\lim_{x\to4}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to 4} \dfrac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x-3}}=\sqrt{7}$. By the $\epsilon-\delta$ limit definition, this means $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta >0 \space(0<|x-4|<\delta \Rightarrow \left |\dfrac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x-3}}-\sqrt{7} \right |<\epsilon)$. Simplifying, we obtain $\left |\dfrac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x-3}}-\sqrt{7} \right |= 
\left |\dfrac{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{7x-21}}{\sqrt{x-3}} \right |$. Let $\delta = \dfrac{3}{4}$, then $|x-4|<\delta\Rightarrow 3.25<x<4.75\Rightarrow\sqrt{x-3}>\sqrt{3.25-3}=\sqrt{0.25}=0.5\Rightarrow \left |\dfrac{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{7x-21}}{\sqrt{x-3}} \right |<\left |\dfrac{(\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{7x-21})\cdot(\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7x-21})}{0.5(\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7x-21})} \right|=\left |\dfrac{-5(x-4)}{0.5(\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7x-21})} \right |< \left |\dfrac{-5(x-4)}{0.5(\sqrt{5.5}+\sqrt{1.75})} \right |<\left| \dfrac{-5(x-4)}{0.5(2+1)}\right|=\dfrac{10}{3}|x-4|$.

Take $\delta = \min\{\dfrac{10}{3}\epsilon,\dfrac{3}{4}\}$ and we have that $\left |\dfrac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x-3}}-\sqrt{7} \right |<\dfrac{10}{3}|x-4|<\dfrac{3}{10}\cdot\dfrac{10}{3}\epsilon=\epsilon$, as required.

Comment: how did you get $\delta$ = $\frac{3}{4}$ ?

Comment: so can i choose different $\delta$  ?

Comment: so i can choose any $\delta$ value as long as it help prove the limit and is $\gt$ 0 . ok then thanks

Comment: does $\sqrt {3x-1}$ must be $\gt 0$ or $\ge 0$ ?

Comment: i still didn't get this part $=\left |\dfrac{-5(x-4)}{0.5(\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7x-21})} \right |< \left |\dfrac{-5(x-4)}{0.5(0-17.5)} \right |=\dfrac{4}{7}|x-4|$. where did you get (0-17.5)? thanks

Comment: @MaxBrian I edited my answer. Sorry about my mistake. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that absolute nonsense. First of all, you can't take the square root of $-17.5$ in the real numbers. Anyways, I basically used the fact that $\delta =\dfrac{3}{4}\Rightarrow |x-4|<\dfrac{3}{4}\Rightarrow x>3.25\Rightarrow \sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7x-21}>\sqrt{5.5}+\sqrt{1.75}$. I just substituted $3.25$ for $x$ in the last step.